# Categories in static lib not regocnized at runtime

Tags: objective-c, gnu-make, gnustep

I am building an executable ("tool") on Linux. Using `include   $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make`.

It's linked to a static lib that has also be build with GNUstep. The lib
contains Categories.

The executable builds fine but has errors at runtime not recognizing
methods defined in the static lib's Category:

```
Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason:  
ClassNameOfClassTheCategoryExtends(instance) does not recognize  
nameOfMethodInCategory
```

I am trying to fix that by passing `-ObjC` to the linker flags (also
tried `-all_load`) in the executable's GNUmakefile:

`ADDITIONAL_LDFLAGS =  -ObjC -all_load`

But that seems to be ignored by clang. Here is the relevant output of
`make install messages=yes debug=yes`

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-ObjC'  
[-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-all_load'  
[-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

It looks like `ADDITIONAL_LDFLAGS` are used compiling, not linking.

Using this leads to the same result:

`LDFLAGS := $(LDFLAGS) -ObjC`

The excecutables `GNUmakefile`includes the following:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make
# My make 
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

The resulting command line output is:

```
$ make install messages=yes debug=yes
This is gnustep-make 2.9.0. Type 'gmake print-gnustep-make-help' for help.
Running in gnustep-make version 2 strict mode.
Making all for tool NameOfExcecutable...
clang -ObjC     -fuse-ld=/usr/bin/ld.gold  -pthread -fexceptions -rdynamic -fobjc-runtime=gnustep-2.0 -fblocks  -o obj/NameOfExcecutable \
./obj/NameOfExcecutable.obj/main.m.o ./obj/NameOfExcecutable.obj/MyClass.m.o ./obj/NameOfExcecutable.obj/StreamRunLoop.m.o ./obj/NameOfExcecutable.obj/Connector.m.o ./obj/NameOfExcecutable.obj/HTTPClient.m.o \
     -L/home/user/GNUstep/Library/Libraries -L/usr/GNUstep/Local/Library/Libraries -L/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries     -lgnustep-base -ldispatch -l/path/to/libOwnLib1.a -l/path/to/libOwnLib2.a -l/path/to/libOwnHavingTheCategories.a -l/path/to/libOwnLib4.a -l/path/to/libOwnLib5.a -luuid -lz -lpthread -ldl   -lpthread -lobjc   -lm

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-ObjC' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

Question:

What am I doing wrong

or

How can I work around the issue?

Comment: Something odd with ours makefile, because flags are used during complication, what is wrong and that is why you are receiving warnings.

Comment: @Cy-4AH: Makes sense. Any idea how to workaround? How to force-pass my flags to the linker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the issue of the linker not knowing the `-ObjC` flag (which we are used to use in Xcode) it looks like:

- only ld.ld64 is aware of this flag
- ld.ld64 is a (too genericly named) "linker for macOS" (from [LLDB.org](https://reviews.llvm.org/D38290))
- thus is not available for Linux linkers

To workaround we first stopped using GNUstep makefiles to
disable all GNUstep magic understand what is going on and wrote our own makefiles.

The actual fix to force link/load all .o files was to explicitly pass `--whole-archive` to the linker:

```
-Wl,-whole-archive path/to/static/lib/containing/categories/libOwnLib1.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive
```